# Change ion-input underline color in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

How can we change the default underline color of a ion-text in only a single page in Ionic 4?

Comment: can't you change it in css?

Comment: I tried border colour it did not work

Comment: did you put `!important` on your css?

Comment: Yes I did, still did not make any difference

Comment: I have same issue, but not solved yet

Comment: It's while we are focus on input box

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The underline is actually a part of the ion-item, not the ion-input.

```
ion-item {
  --border-color: var(--ion-color-danger, #f1453d);
}
```

Comment: For future viewers, this code still works fine to set the default underline. To change the underline color on invalid / touched: ```ion-item.ion-invalid.ion-touched { --border-color: var(--ion-color-danger); }``` - Ionic V5.2

Answer (score 10):

Ionic 4.x uses **CSS Custom Properties** for most of the time.

`src/app/pages/test/test.page.scss`

```
:host {
    ion-item {
        --border-color: white; // default underline color
        --highlight-color-invalid: red; // invalid underline color
        --highlight-color-valid: green; // valid underline color
    }
}
```

If necessary, please check the other custom properties [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item#css-custom-properties).

Comment: Works.  Took me ages to find this. Thanks.  You don't need the :host if you put this in your global.scss

Answer (score 8):

For Ionic V4.X is a little bit diffrent.

You can open *specific_page.scss* file where you want to change *ion-input* border when input value is **Valid** o **Invalid**

Change the colors of the following class, like this:

```
:host {
   .item-interactive.ion-invalid{
    --highlight-background: yellow !important;
  }
  .item-interactive.ion-valid{
    --highlight-background: black !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow! you saved my day. Works like charm.I'm using Ionic 5.

Answer (score 7):

Try this css

```
.item-has-focus{
   --highlight-background: #e2e2e2;
}
```

Comment: This works well when placed in the global.scss with Ionic 4/5

Comment: but it does also overwrite the valid feedback. e.g. if you say min length 6 and you enter 6 or more the color will go to green. with your solution it will stay on the defined color.

Answer (score 1):

To aggregate in app.scss file

```
.ios {
    .item-has-focus.ion-invalid {
      --border-color: var(--ion-color-danger, #f1453d);
    }

   .ion-valid {
      --border-color: var(
        --ion-item-border-color,
        var(--ion-border-color, var(--ion-color-step-150, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)))
      );
   }

   .custom-item {
      --background: transparent;
      color: #fff !important;
      --background-focused: transparent;
   }
}

.md.custom-item {
    --background: transparent;
    color: #fff !important;
    --background-focused: transparent;
    --border-color: var(--ion-item-border-color, var(--ion-border-color, var(--ion-color-step-150, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)))
    );
}
```

Or use class to you custom `.custom-item.hydrated.ion-touched.ion-dirty.ion-invalid.item-label.item-interactive.item-input.item-has-focus.item.ios.ion-focusable`