# How to change the color of the underline in ion-datetime on invalid date?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I want to change the color of the underline on invalid date to red. I have not tried anything yet because there are no similar question in the internet.

[image: Ionic Form]

Below is the code for Date and Time:

```
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'picker'">
    <ion-item no-padding class="item-icons">
        <ion-label [attr.missing-detail]="missingDetail(field.formControlName) ? '' : null"
            class="form-label"
            stacked>
            {{ (field.label | translate) + ': ' + isFieldRequired(field.validators.required)}}
        </ion-label>
        <ion-datetime 
            [max]="field.validators?.max ? field.validators?.max : null"
            [required]="field.validators?.required"                            
            (ionChange)="refreshDateTimePicker(field.formControlName)"
            [formControlName]="field.formControlName"
            [cancelText]="'COMMON.CANCEL' | translate" [doneText]="'COMMON.DONE' | translate"
            [displayFormat]="field.others.displayFormat" [pickerFormat]="field.others.pickerFormat">
        </ion-datetime>
        <mat-icon item-right [svgIcon]="field.others.icon"></mat-icon>
    </ion-item>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change ion-input underline color in Ionic 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214736/change-ion-input-underline-color-in-ionic-4)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSS Custom Properties](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-variables) to it. Add it to the scss file of the component.

```
:host {
  ion-item {
      --border-color: white; // default underline color
      --highlight-color-invalid: pink; // invalid underline color
      --highlight-color-valid: yellow; // valid underline color
  }
}
```

Read more https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item#css-custom-properties

Credits: [Milan Chandro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3867422/milan-chandro)'s answer to [Change ion-input underline color in Ionic 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214736/change-ion-input-underline-color-in-ionic-4/58427925#58427925)